# Play Framework 2.1 and NewSQL

Tags: playframework, ebean, nuodb, nosql

This is more a curiosity question:

I have an application developed using Ebean and mySQL that works just peachy bot in "production" (evolutions turned off) and dev mode (DDL and evo On). I came accross some NewSQL solutions that seemed interesting and managed (without changing the code ... at all) to make it work on NuoDB in prod mode, but not dev mode because the driver was not supporting the creation of the play_evolutions table, somehow. That proved to me that this is possible ... at least in production.

I am not particularly attached to NuoDB to be frank, I just want to see what the current state of the art of NewSQL could do performance wize for my app.

So my real question: is there a NewSQL solution out there that would work flawlessly for evolutions and DDL using the right jdbc drivers for it? Or has anyone had any experience with NewSQL and play? Can someone point me in other good NewSQL directions?

Bonus question: Is there a way to set NuoDB to work seemlessly under Ebean and play framework?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting question, are you open to trying another NewSQL solution? (Disclaimer: I work at Clustrix). I don't know that any of our customers use Ebean, but we use standard MySQL JDBC drivers and are compatible with other ORMs. If you're up for giving Clustrix a try, we would work to make Ebean work for you and can assist if needed through a performance exercise. http://www.clustrix.com/try-clustrix-now/

Comment: Well I would be open to try anything that is reliable. I do need it to work on every step of the development with play framework 2.1. Which means supporting play evolutions and Ebean. Supporting Ebean without evolution seems to be down to providing a good jdbc driver for your platform (like NuoDB did).

Comment: Clustrix is compatible with standard MySQL drivers - there should be no issue . In terms of being reliable - Clustrix supports production deployments all over the world. We have a Proof of Concept program (http://www.clustrix.com/the-clustrix-poc-program) that sounds like it would be a great way to see what Clustrix can do with your application. Email me clieu at clustrix dot com and I can help get you set up!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a NewSQL solution out there that would work flawlessly for evolutions and DDL using the right jdbc drivers for it?

Yes, [Clustrix](http://www.clustrix.com) uses MySQL JDBC drivers and is a NewSQL solution

Comment: Is there a way to get access to a free dev/community version of Clustrix to test it? I need my sysops to know how set it up and to run heavy load tests on them on the machines of our choice.

Comment: Clustrix is currently available as an Appliance, as a Database as a Service (backed by the appliance) and in AWS (starting next week) There is a free/dev version of Clustrix, but it is limited and should be used for compatibility testing only (not load tests). If you are interested in running heavy load testing, there is a (free) Proof of Concept program where your team can have access to Clustrix in any of the available offerings (appliance, DBaaS, AWS). There is also software download version planned -- contact us to find out more :)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, NuoDB leverages a pure JDBC drive and is also NewSQL and has the benefit of easy scalability.